# ChromeOS: error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:

Tags: linux, debian, google-chrome-os, crostini

I'm working with chromeos 80 and am using debian buster in crostini. I want to use the snap package manager. When I try:

```
~$sudo snap install hello-world
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
   /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-962423259: mount failed: Operation not permitted.
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: sudo modprobe loop will only work on archlinux not debian not to mention it's debian on crostini. I'm working on the same issue maybe I'll post when I find a solution.

Comment: my guess is crostini has it mounted with noexec or nodev

Comment: please edit your .bashrc or .profile or /etc/environment and update your path or you can share me your rc file or give you any image

Answer (score 50):

Try this way to install SNAPD

```
sudo apt install libsquashfuse0 squashfuse fuse 
sudo apt install snapd
```

Now select package name:

```
sudo snap install gimp
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work with ubuntu 18.04 though. libsquashfuse0 doesnt exist and without it, the error persists.

Comment: @phil294 - initial question is specific to Chrome OS, which runs Debian Buster in VM; can confirm `sudo apt install libsquashfuse0 squashfuse fuse` resolved the issue for me on my Pixelbook.

Comment: I used this to install Webstorm from Snap and it worked. Did it on a Asus Chromebox. Just curious about why or how `libsquashfuse0 squashfuse fuse` works

Comment: Great answer, solved my problem !

Comment: `Failed to write 'change' to '/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/uevent': Permission denied` and the relevant directory: 
rwxr-xr-x 5 nobody nogroup 0 Dec 19 09:15 /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/

This is with Debian 11 (bullseye) on a Chromebook: `Linux penguin 5.4.151-16908-gff376e5d5ee1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Dec 11 19:28:06 PST 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: This fixed the issue in `Kali` Linux

Comment: I can confirm this works for ChromeOS Flex too

Comment: Does not works for Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS x86_64 `Unable to locate package libsquashfuse0`

Answer (score 7):

Under CentOS 8 we have a file `/etc/modprobe.d/CIS.conf` with all unused file systems disabled. Removing the line: `install squashfs /bin/true` resolves the error

Comment: better find where it `sudo grep -R "squashfs" /etc/modprobe.d/`

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`sudo modprobe loop`

[Here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cannot-mount-squashfs-image-using-squashfs-operation-not-permitted/13829/8) is a relevant forum post based on your error.

Answer (score 2):

On Centos or Fedora:

```bash
sudo dnf install squashfs-tools squashfuse
```

Comment: Only this may not solve issue. Need to remove this `install squashfs /bin/true`  also

Comment: This did not work for me on F37. There also was no file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` containing `install squashfs /bin/true`

Comment: This also works on AlmaLinux. But I had to additionally install fuse: `dnf install fuse`

Answer (score 1):

Under Redhat7 we have a file `/etc/modprobe.d/NCIRC.conf` with all unused file systems disabled. Removing the line: `install squashfs /bin/true` resolves the error here as well

Comment: I donot have this file in my system

Comment: Try a more generic approach.  Go to /etc/modprobe.d directory and grep squashfs * 
Edit the file that references the line above, and comment it out with leading #.
I had this issue, followed this process, and resolved the problem.  No restarting of anything is necessary.  Just comment out the line, and snap install works.