# Snap is Unable to mount it's squashfs image on Debian Buster Crostini

Tags: debian, google-chrome-os, squashfs, crostini

I need help with a big problem with Snap Package Manager on Debian Buster Crostini. Whenever I try to install Anbox with Snap package manager, it gives me the error:

```
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using
   "squashfs": mount: /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-772933788: mount failed:
   Operation not permitted.
```

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859806/chromeos-error-system-does-not-fully-support-snapd-cannot-mount-squashfs-imag for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try this command I found on Reddit:

```
sudo apt install libsquashfuse0 squashfuse fuse
```

Comment: Thank you, works well and solved this problem (for me).

Comment: I also had to load loop.  "sudo modprobe loop"

Comment: I had to add `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free` into my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and do `apt update`. My original repositories list didn't contain the `squashfuse` package.